# Am I missing a dependency in my global.asax.cs file for connecting to Azure Cosmos?

Tags: botframework, azure-cosmosdb

I'm new to the Bot Framework and inline with best practice, I've been trying to connect to an Azure Cosmos DB to manage state data.

The code below compiles without any issues, but as soon as I try and test the bot in Test Web Bot screen in Azure, it authorizes with the Bot, but it doesn't connect, so I'm unable to test the database connectivity.

I've been developing the Bot using v3 of the SDK and tried amending the out of the box by removing the comment line regarding Cosmos DB initially, but that failed to compile, so have been tinkering around with the code below, which compiles, but doesn't appear to initiate the Bot.

```
using System;
using Autofac;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;

namespace SimpleEchoBot
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            // Bot Storage: This is a great spot to register the private state storage for your bot. 
            // We provide adapters for Azure Table, CosmosDb, SQL Azure, or you can implement your own!
            // For samples and documentation, see: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure

            var uri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["uri"]);
            var key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accesskey"];
            var store = new DocumentDbBotDataStore(uri, key);

            Conversation.UpdateContainer(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.Register(c => store)
                        .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
                        .AsSelf()
                        .SingleInstance();
                    builder.Register(c => new CachingBotDataStore(store, CachingBotDataStoreConsistencyPolicy.ETagBasedConsistency))
                        .As<IBotDataStore<BotData>>()
                        .AsSelf()
                        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
                });
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be that the Bot initializes, but fails to do so.

Comment: I am wondering, is the compiler stepping over this line: `var store = new DocumentDbBotDataStore(uri, key);
` or is it hanging there? Is the `store` parameter getting initialised?

Comment: Since you are just new to the framework, I would suggest starting with v4 (unless you have a specific need to use or support v3). In v4, you would configure the state store in Startup.cs. Please find a sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/351c4747a32b2e40c1fe2db6c73203720dea3e2b/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt/Startup.cs#L90). Otherwise, do you have an answer to Nick's question?

Comment: Thank you, I started over using v4 Node.JS. Thank you both for your advice.